# Pronouncing the word "getting"

Tags: pronunciation

When some people pronounce the word "getting", it sounds to me like they're saying something like "get'n". Is that some kind of dialect?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, it is not part of any English dialect - it is slang, just like "gettin'".

Comment: No! *get'n* ***is*** *gettin'*. That is, people hardly ever write *get'n*, and when they write down *gettin'*, there's a good chance that they're talking about the pronunciation *get'n*.